# How do I keep stored passwords from Ubuntu 10.04?

Tags: password

I want to re-install the PC my mother uses and since she's not very handy with computers, she has a bunch of passwords stored in Firefox which she probably forgot and won't be able to enter again.

The current system is Ubuntu 10.04. I want to install Lubuntu 11.10. How do I ensure that after re-installing the system, all her stored passwords will remain stored and pre-filled in all the websites she currently uses?

Also, I'd like to install google chrome instead of firefox, so they should be available in google chrome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Everything personal is stored in your home directory, which is usually /home/username. Copy that somewhere, install the new system, copy it back into the new system and set permissions.

I think the new installer has an option to keep the home directory, but be sure to take a backup in any case.

Answer (score 0):

try Using firefox sync feature.

https://wiki.mozilla.org/Firefox_Sync